# How did Gauss find the units of the cubic field $\mathbb Q[n^{1/3}]$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ho.history-overview

Recently I read the National Mathematics Magazine article "**[Bell - Gauss and the Early Development of Algebraic Numbers](https://doi.org/10.2307/3030061)**", which gives a good description of the genesis of Gauss's ideas regarding the foundations of algebraic number theory. Among other pieces of useful information, it mentions a certain ternary cubic form which Gauss studied in 1808 in connection with his attempts to understand the underlying principles of higher reciprocity laws (cubic reciprocity in this case).

The particular form is:
$$\varphi(x,y,z) = x^3 + ny^3 + n^2z^3 - 3nxyz$$ and Gauss attempted to find (rational) solutions to the Diophantine equation $\varphi(x,y,z) = 1$. As the article explains, this particular form arises as the norm of the number $t=x+vy+v^2z$ (here $v = m\epsilon$, where $m=|n^{1/3}|$ and $\epsilon^3=1$) in the pure cubic field created by adjoining $v$ to the field of rationals, which is the product of $t$ with its two conjugate elements $t_1,t_2$:

$$\varphi(t) = t\cdot t_1\cdot t_2 = (x+ym\epsilon+zm^2\epsilon^2)(x+ym\epsilon^2+zm^2\epsilon)(x+ym+zm^2) = x^3+m^3y^3+m^6z^3+3m^3xyz(\epsilon+\epsilon^2) = x^3+ny^3+n^2z^3-3nxyz$$

(I omitted $18$ terms whose sum is zero, and $\epsilon+\epsilon^2=-1$ so hence the last equality.) Since Gauss wanted to know where this expression equals 1, this investigation can be interpreted as an attempt to find the units (numbers of norm 1) in this cubic field.

I checked in Gauss's work and the relevant pages are p.21-26 from volume 8, where he denotes the norm of an algebraic (cubic) integer $t$ by $\varphi(t)$. In [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBynB.png) he established several basic properties of the norm function (under "Theorem I"); that the norm function is homogenous and multiplicative. In [2] he writes down the minimal polynomial of $t = x+vy+v^2z$ (when only integer coefficients are allowed) in his notation, which in our notation translates into:

$$t^3-3xt^2+3(x^2-nyz)t-(x^3 + ny^3 + n^2z^3 - 3nxyz)=0,$$

note that the norm $\varphi(t)$ is the free coefficient, so it equals $t\cdot t_1\cdot t_2$ (and this is exactly the definition of the algebraic norm). In [3] he characterizes prime numbers that are representable by this cubic form as those for which $n$ is a cubic residue.

At the end of this fragment there are two numeric tables, the first gives the fundamental unit of $\mathbb Q[2^{1/3}]$, together with its inverse unit and their first nine powers, and the second table gives the units reciprocal to the fundamental units of the cubic field $\mathbb Q[n^{1/3}]$ for certain values of $n$ between $2$ and $37$. As franz lemmermeyer remarked in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3108785) to the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106490/how-did-gauss-find-the-units-of-the-cubic-field-qn1-3) posted on math.stackexchange, the solvability (in integers) of the equation above as well as the fact that each solution arises by taking powers of the fundamental solution (the fundamental unit) is a special case of Dirichlet's unit theorem.

While verifing the correctness of some data in the second numeric table (using some tables available on web), I noticed that the calculations involved relatively large numbers, so I guess searching for these reciprocal fundamental units without some useful algorithm is very computationally inefficient. Therefore, I believe Gauss might have used some algorithm to increase searching efficiency.  I added the second table here, just to illustrate the complexity invloved.

[image]

What is most interesting to me is a remark by Fricke on a certain strange handnote Gauss wrote next to [2]:

> In Gauss's handwriting you can find the following note
>
> - Correction of $v$ is roughly: $$-\frac{D^2}{9BC^2}$$

Here $D$ is Gauss's notation for the norm (he replaces $\varphi$ with $D$), and $A= b^2-ac,B=nc^2-ab, C=a^2-nbc$ (where $t = a+bv+cv^2$). If $t$ is a unit, than $A,B,C$ are actually related to $t$ through the relation: $t^{-1} = C+Bv+Av^2$. This note is "strange" to me because I don't understand what is meant by "correction of $v$" — isn't $v$ supposed to be constant ($v=n^{1/3}$)?

Despite not having an idea what is the meaning of correction, one thing I noticed is that it is an homogeneous function of the form. That is, the norm $D$ is homogeneous of degree $3$, $B$ and $C$ are homogeneous of degree $2$, and therefore $-\frac{D^2}{9BC^2}$ is homogeneous of degree $0$. This means that the correction is invariant with respect to multiplication of the cubic integer $t$ with a real integer; that is, if $(x,y,z) = x+vy+v^2z$, then its supposed "correction" is the same as for every integer multiple of $(x',y',z') = (\frac{x}{gcd(x,y,z)},\frac{y}{gcd(x,y,z)},\frac{z}{gcd(x,y,z)})$. I hope this invariance property might help give a clue about the kind of arithmetic process for which Gauss needed to make corrections in the value of $v$.

In addition, I noticed now that in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBynB.png) Gauss describes a certain iterative arithmetic procedure that apparently involves corrections in the values of $v$; for example, at the end [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBynB.png) he writes:

$$t = 1, t'=v, t''= \frac{t'v'}{l'}, t''' = \frac{t''v''}{l''}, etc.$$

He also uses the notation $Div$, which I believe is an abbreviation for "Divisor", since the arithmetical procedure he describes involves the greatest common divisor of the coefficients of the element $t$ of the cubic field. I don't have any idea what is the procedure he descibes, but maybe it is related to the algorithm he used to construct his table of fundamental units (this is the only passage that looks like a description of algorithm).

***Note*** that finding a unit of $\mathbb Q[n^{1/3}]$ for small values of $n$ is not always  difficult computationally - for a given $n$ one can calculate norms of elements of this field for modest values of $x,y,z$ by taking different combinations of values; if the norms of two different elements happen to be equal (which is very likely to happen!), one can calculate the quotient of these elements, so by the multiplicative property of the norm function $\varphi$ one gets an element of norm $1$. The real issue, however, is how to get the fundamental unit (even for $2\le n\le 12$ one gets very large numbers in the calculations).

So my questions are:

- **What was Gauss's procedure**? **and how did he find fundamental units**?
- **What is the meaning of Gauss's note (about the correction of $v$)**?

**General outline to reconstruct Gauss's procedure (Update from 5.12.23)**

Since there are infinitely many solutions of this ternary cubic equation, Gauss must have had the following ingredients:

- A criterion according to which a unit is smallest in a suitable sense; units satisfing this criterion cannot be generated as a power of a "smaller" unit. In the quadratic case, the criterion for a binary form to be the "reduced" representative of its class is a certain inequallity satisfied by its coefficients and its discriminant, such that it belongs to the fundamental domain. Of course, Gauss must have had an argument to justify why cubic units satisfing his criterion must be fundamental units.
- A terminating reduction algorithm which starts with one unit and generates succesive units of the same cubic field. This reduction terminates when the unit satisfies the criterion of minimality.

Since the quadratic form of the Pell equation, which is $x^2-Dy^2$, is the principal form among binary quadratic forms (the theory of Pell equation, as well that of reduction of binary quadratic forms, was fully treated in chapter 5 of Disquisitions Arithmeticae), and the Gauss cubic [norm form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_form) is the principal form among ternary cubic forms, I believe there might be some analogy in the procedures.

This suggests that Gauss did not need to develop a comprehensive theory of cubic forms (which is very subtle and modern, if judged by the vast literature on it), but only do so for principal ternary cubics, in analogy with Pell equation.

Comment: I have added (nt.number-theory) - based on the recommendation that questions on MO should [have at least one top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1457/why-are-mo-tags-formatted-as-they-are). I'd guess ([tag:ho.history-overview]) might be suitable here, too.

Comment: Here is the same question on Mathematics: [How did Gauss find the units of the cubic field $Q[n^{1/3}]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3106490)
I think that [this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638) gives a very reasonable advice about [meta-tag:cross-posting]. The most important point is to include links to other copies.

Comment: There are two differences between Gauss's table and the one given in [Project Euler](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy/volume-46/issue-10.S1/A-table-of-fundamental-units-of-purely-cubic-fields/10.3792/pja/1195526509.full). First, Gauss chose the positive unit with the smallest absolute sum of coefficients, which may be the reciprocal of the value in Project Euler. The Project Euler values, picked to be greater than $1$, may be much larger especially when the Gauss coefficients gave mixed signs.

Comment: The second difference is the Gauss table considers only integer coefficients on the factors $1,\sqrt[3]n,\sqrt[3]n^2$. This misses the fundamental unit in many cases (as it does in the quadratic case). In the cubic case the coefficients on the fundamental units may even be divided by $6$; see the Project Euler entry for a radicand of $28$.

Comment: Your [1], [2], and [3] are presumably references to a bibliography; am I missing the bibliography?  (I assume the Markdown conversion of [1] to a link to your image is unintentional.)

Comment: @LSpice - here is the link to the fragment from which Gauss's table was taken: https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN236010751?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B27%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22scan%22%7D (it is from volume 8 of Gauss's works). I also believe that another fragment, from volume 2, is also relavent to the discussion here: https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN23599524X?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B391%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22scan%22%7D. The last fragment deals with norms of complex integers.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322954/how-did-gauss-find-the-units-of-the-cubic-field-mathbb-qn1-3#comment1191382_322954), I'm sorry, I'm still confused.  Are you saying that [1], [2], and [3] refer to https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN236010751?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B27%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22scan%22%7D , https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN23599524X?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B391%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22scan%22%7D , and some third fragment, respectively?

Comment: No need to apologize... [1], [2] and [3] all refer to the first link in my last comment. I just added the second link because it is also relavent here and might help answer my question. And there is no third fragment - the  section dealing with norms is in the fragment in this second link.

Comment: Version 18 of this question.